# Replace exact string present in one column with another column of a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with four column.

[image]

I want to replace the exact occurrence of the replace_char column in the address field of the dataframe with standard_word column.

In the first row the "Rd" present in "RdJeffrey" should not be replaced but the "Rd" at the end should be replaced with "Road"

Expected output

[image]

This is what I tried but the code is failing.

`

```
    import re
    def replace_only_whole_word(search_string, input_string, 
    replace_word):
    # Create a raw string with word boundaries from the user's 
    input_string
    raw_search_string = r"\b" + search_string + r"\b"

    match_output = re.search(raw_search_string, input_string)
    no_match_was_found = (match_output is None)
    if no_match_was_found:
       return input_string
    
    else:
       return re.sub(raw_search_string, replace_word, input_string)

    if __name__ == '__main__':

         spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    address = [(1, "14851 RdJeffrey Rd", "Rd", "Road"),
           (2, "43421 St. Margarita St", "St" , "Street"),
           (3, "Ave No 13111 Siemon Avet", "Ave", "Avenue")]


    df = spark.createDataFrame(address, ["id", "address", "replace_char", "standard_word"])
    df.show(truncate=False)
    df.withColumn("changed_value", 
    replace_only_whole_word(df["replace_char"], df["address"], df["standard_word"])).show()
```

`

The above program gives me the error
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```scala
dataset
  .withColumn("split", functions.split(col("address"), " "))
  .withColumn("replaced",
    expr("transform(split, x -> case when (x == replace_char) then standard_word else x end)")
  )
  .withColumn("result", array_join(col("replaced"), " "))
```

The idea is to first split on individual words, check if the individual word matches `replace_char` column, and finally concatenate back

Final result looks like below (I left added columns as part of the table for the sake of clarity):

```
+---+------------------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
|ip |address                 |replace_char|standard_word|split                         |replaced                         |result                     |
+---+------------------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
|1  |14851 RdJeffrey Rd      |Rd          |Road         |[14851, RdJeffrey, Rd]        |[14851, RdJeffrey, Road]         |14851 RdJeffrey Road       |
|2  |43421 St. Margarita St  |St          |Street       |[43421, St., Margarita, St]   |[43421, St., Margarita, Street]  |43421 St. Margarita Street |
|3  |Ave No 13111 Siemon Avet|Ave         |Avenue       |[Ave, No, 13111, Siemon, Avet]|[Avenue, No, 13111, Siemon, Avet]|Avenue No 13111 Siemon Avet|
+---+------------------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Good luck!